# What are some research papers or techniques that deals with fitting clothes on a human?

Tags: machine-learning, reference-request, image-processing, computer-vision

Given an image of a dress (from different angles), what could be ways to fit it on a human image (again multiple angles corresponding to dress)? Any link to research papers or tutorial regarding this?

Comment: Where have you looked yourself? Have you searched with Google Scholar? Which journales and conferences of the field have you checked out?

Comment: Yes I have searched on Google Scholar and did a Google Search too but I haven't found anything meaningful for my purpose. Any specific journals or conferences would you like to suggest where should I look?

Answer (score 1):

I would expect most of the works use Generative Adversarial Networks (GANs) for this because they are powerful generative models capable of learning the complex underlying probability distribution.

In this amazing work the authors used a Conditional GAN, in which they can generate an image conditioned on semantic segmentation map. In your case, you might want to condition on two images, one of a dress and the other of a human. https://github.com/NVIDIA/pix2pixHD

You might also want to look at the [ICCV 2019 workshop on fashion](https://sites.google.com/view/cvcreative/home).